# Secret Class: FragmentManagerImpl?

Tags: java, android

I have the android source code and i am looking through the classes one strange thing is i cant find any api or source code for this class :FragmentManagerImpl the only reference i found was in the Activity class source which is:

```
            final FragmentManagerImpl mFragments = new FragmentManagerImpl();
```

Comment: find anything? Just wondering looking for the source too

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted or make a comment if not.

Answer (score 3):

It's an inner class inside `FragmentManager`.

Here's the link:
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager.java#FragmentManagerImpl

Comment: Any idea where it is in the Google version? https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/tools_r22.2/v4/java/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.java| NM here... https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/tools_r22.2/v4/java/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager.java

Comment: In the 2nd link you've posted, go to line 393.

Comment: fixed the broken link